# What does byte& mean?

Tags: c#, .net

```
//
string productName;
byte& local1 = (byte&) productName;
//
```

What is this byte&?
I really don't understand. I got code from my friend but I don't understand what this line wants to tell? Because it gives error or redline in my VS2012. Can anyone explain?

Comment: this is not valid C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's making `local1` a reference byte type, but that's probably coming from some IL decompilation and not valid C# syntax. That result code will more likely happen if you decompile a IL function with a `ref string` parameter.

You can't compile that code using a C# compiler. There are many things that are legal in IL but there's no C# equivalent syntax, and that's usually the way it's decompiled back (which doesn't make it compilable) in a best-effort to make it look like C#

Comment: Thank You for your detailed answer as this will help me understood code.

Answer (score 0):

It is invalid. The closest syntax is byte? - which adds null support to byte.

Comment: I'd say the closest syntax would be `byte* local1 = (byte*)&productName` on a `unsafe` scope. Nullables are not even close to anything related to that syntax

Comment: They are equally close in that both are a type followed by a punctuation character. I wasn't inferring functional closeness. There is no way to know what was intended by the original syntax - you make an excellent alternative suggestion and looking at it, does make more sense functionally.

Comment: I know... mine is not even the same (it'd make a "byte pointer", and not a "byte reference"), but that's how most decompilers translate that kind of functionality from IL. Usually to make it look like a mix of C++ pointer and VB.Net's "Name&" syntax. But you are right: since it's invalid C#, one can only guess here.

Comment: These code is actually a decompiled code that my friend gave me. I was really shocked when I google about `byte&` and there is nothing  that came up. Thank You @Jcl for your answer.